# What country is the movie Babe set in, in-universe?

Tags: babe

The movie *Babe*, featuring a pig that wants to be a sheepdog, was filmed in New South Wales, Australia.  However, my memory has failed me as to where it was supposed to be set in-universe.  The farmer appears to have some sort of Englishesque accent, the animals have varying accents, and I can't recall what the judges had.

What is the in-universe setting of *Babe*?

[image: Ifyoucanseethisyouredoinginsomethingwrong]

Comment: Is there anything that makes you doubt in the inherent premise of it being set in the very country it was produced in?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That's not inherent in the least. *Most* movies are produced elsewhere.

Comment: Also remember that at Christmas-time it seems like summer-time weather - so that would seem to say something southern hemisphere

Comment: One word comes to my mind: Canada.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No location is ever mentioned in the movie. In fact, the sequel *Babe: Pig In The City* has Babe travelling to a city called “Metropolis.” In that movie, you can see structures that resemble the Golden Gate Bridge, Sears Tower, World Trade Center, Sydney Opera House and Christ The Redeemer, among others. So, it’s safe to say that there was no intended country or location for the movies.

Comment: So... Babe takes place in the DC universe? :D

Comment: ...or some [**a futuristic urban dystopia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_(1927_film))

Comment: Or Legoland, since it probably has most or all of those structures.

Comment: This reminds me of Springfield in the Simpsons bordering [Ohio, Nevada, Maine, and Kentucky](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Springfield's_State#What_state_is_Springfield_in.3F). It has elements of several things that cannot coexist in the real world.

Answer (score 40):

From [**IMDB**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112431/trivia)

> The location of the film is never mentioned, though scenery and architecture suggest somewhere in Great Britain.
>
> However, except for two announcers only heard for a few seconds on the TV, everyone speaks with **American** accents. Moreover, cars were driven on the right side of the road, while in Great Britain [and Australia] cars are driven on the left.

Suffice it to say, it's deliberately left to the imagination as to the location.

Comment: "everyone speaks with American accents" Um, what?  It's been a long time since I've seen the movie but  I don't remember any of the people speaking with an American accent.

Comment: +1, I had previously assumed it was in New Zealand (couldn't say why, haven't seen it in years), but they drive on the left in NZ.

Comment: @Kevin Sounds American to this American: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjQtzV9IZ0Q

Comment: That doesn't sound American to me.

Comment: Well it's not an English accent to this Brit...but I suppose I could change it to "mid-Atlantic" or "indeterminate" accent...but it's a quote not my statement..even though I agree with it.

Comment: @Kevin Try this instead https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0pOWMHRgfI

Answer (score 17):

Based on some of the phrases used and minor pieces of evidence from the script, I would say the film is most likely to be set in **Britain**, probably northern England as in the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheep-Pig):

- > National Grand Challenge Sheepdog Trials

  An event with this *exact* name doesn't seem to exist anywhere in the real world, but there are [English National Sheepdog Trials](http://www.englishnationalsheepdogtrials.org.uk/2016-english-national/), as well as [Irish](http://www.irishnationalsheepdogtrials.org.uk/), [Scottish](http://www.scottishnationalsheepdogtrials.org.uk/), and [Welsh](http://www.welshnationalsheepdogtrials.org.uk/) National Sheepdog Trials.
- > National Sheepdog Association

  For some reason I couldn't find a website for this organisation, but [searching for this phrase on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=national+sheepdog+association&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=shK_V6veFqbS8AfsupbABg#q=%22national+sheepdog+association%22) and excluding results relating to this film seems to turn up only UK-based results.
- > I know I have to be at the National Conference. I am the Assistant General Secretary of the Northeast Region after all.

  I asked an American (the OP of this question, in fact) whether this sounds like the sort of title a person might have in the US, and got the answer no. Nor could it be Australian: the northeast region of Australia is pretty much unpopulated.
- > Coming today from the Kingsmith Showground in the heart of sheep country.

  As far as I know, there is no "sheep country" in the US (again, I consulted some Americans, who confirmed my suspicion). This term might be used in Australia (though it's not universally known there), and it's definitely a phrase one might hear in Britain.

  (Incidentally "Kingsmith" is clearly a nod to Dick King-Smith, who wrote the source novel.)

Comment: As a Brit I can tell  you the accents are most definitely **not** from the North of England....not even close. The source material is certainly British but those accents...nope. :)

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm also a Brit ... but it's been about 15 years since I watched this film, so I'm just going by the transcript :-)

Comment: No deserts in the northeast of Australia. That's a very un-deserty tropical region. Our deserts are all in the middle. If an Australian used "region" in a context like that it would be more likely they were referring to a region inside a state or even a region within some other kind of division.

Comment: I'm not sure if Australia has a an area called "sheep country" by anyone or even if sheep farming is within any roughly contiguous area. But we would definitely use such a turn of phrase to refer to all the sheep-farming areas generally even if they are not totally contiguous.

Comment: @hippietrail Australia definitely does have a distinct "sheep country" region: http://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/11/dingo-fence-australias-5600km-dog-fence.html

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Yes I can't even manage to Google up a map of sheep farming in Australia. I can find the phrase "sheep country" used a lot, includings in news sources. It seems more to describe a type of place rather than "a place" or any specific area.

Comment: @randal'thor: It's not accurate to say the northeast is pretty much unpopulated. The two largest population centres, Townsville and Cairns have over 300,000 on their own. Population is far more sparse further north than Port Douglas and on the western side of the Cape York peninsula. Another thing to note is that the thinly populated non-desert areas in Australia are typically taken up by farmland. Anyway the setting doesn't look like north Queensland but could easily be say northeastern Victoria, the state in our southeast corner. Northeast NSW doesn't sound wrong either.

Comment: New Zealand (where it was filmed) has one as well: [New Zealand Sheep Dog Trial Association](http://www.sheepdogtrials.co.nz/). If I'm reading things right there they have separate championships for the north and south islands, and then one big (one might say "grand") championship for both.

Comment: For a while, the ABC was televising competitions, so people did (and do) take it seriously, NZ too.. The dogs are most definitely Australian, and it would have been hard to import them otherwise.

Comment: In the movie, the weather during Christmas appears quite warm, and everything around is completely green. Can December in England (esp. Northern England) look like this? When I heard them talking about Christmas, and compared this with how the surroundings look and whateveryone is wearing, I thought it's got to be either one of the Southern states in USA or somewhere down under.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are all helpful, and it seems the consensus is that it could be many countries, and is (possibly deliberately) vague.

However it is useful to know that the original tale was apparently set in the UK, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheep-Pig) (yes, I know). If anyone has read it and can confirm then that would be useful.

> The Sheep-Pig, or Babe, the Gallant Pig in the U.S., is a children's novel by Dick King-Smith, first published by Gollancz in 1983 with illustrations by Mary Rayner. Set in rural England, where King-Smith spent twenty years as a farmer, it features a lone pig on a sheep farm.

The original question referenced the film, and so this is arguably not an entirely valid answer... and yet the actual question was 'What is the in-universe setting of Babe?' and it seems that this is the closest we will come to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the farmer's wife is a member of the Country Women's Association, an Australian association. I'm not sure if this was a mistake or not. However, I believe the filmmakers wanted to make it deliberately vague. To me it is overtly Australian.

Answer (score 0):

Although the movie was supposed to be set in **UK**, it was in fact filmed in **Robertson** in the **Southern Highlands of New South Wales**.

I appeared as the man in grey who chased **Rex** off the field.